# MonoDevelop extract method

Tags: c#

I'm using MonoDevelop v5.10 and I can't get Extract method to work. I highlight the method I want extracted, right click to select extract method and nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: The refactoring feature does not work for all cases based on my own test. In edge cases you will have to manually extract the method.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't got it to work at all. I just manually extract it.